# Two iPhones, two phone numbers - how to link the other number on one?

Tags: iphone

I have two iPhones using different SIMs and phone #s

I want to keep calls connected to the same phone number that is on the device, however, I want to link my other phone number (which is not in the SIM that's in the phone) to that device as well.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Can't you just configure call forwarding from one phone to the other? Depending on your contract this may bring additional costs though.